# composer имеет странное условие, в результате работает только autoload_static.php

Tags: php, composer

Вопрос для знатоков.

Composer формирует autoload_real.php , где пишет

```
$useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600
  && !defined('HHVM_VERSION')
  && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());
```

Всё бы хорошо, но я хочу использовать psr-4, а в результате следующего кода

```
if ($useStaticLoader) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';
    call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit3a3dfe04f2fa57486301b1f3513a2c3f::getInitializer($loader));
} else {
    $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
    foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
        $loader->set($namespace, $path);
    }

    $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
    foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
        $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
    }

    $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
    if ($classMap) {
        $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
    }
}
```

я имею возможность работать только classmap.

Я с композером начинаю только работать, буду признателен, если разжуёте.

PS Самостоятельно искать пробовал.

Comment: не обращайте внимания на <pre>, это я с редактором не стал возиться, речь идёт, конечно о php

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4 ?

Comment: @E_p у меня вообще ен генерится
 vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php
из-за указанной проблемы. у меня php7, всегда выполняется условие, всегда формируется classmap и никогда vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php.

Comment: Покажите `composer.json`.

Comment: @E_p
{
  "name": "autoloader",
  "description": "DEMO",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "NAME",
      "email": "mailmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr4":{
      "application\\":"application",
      "model\\":"model"
    },
    "classmap":["application","model"]
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего проблема была в следующем: я пользовался composer.phar - а он всегда свежей версии, а в свежих версиях есть фикс, который и является

```
$useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600
  && !defined('HHVM_VERSION')
  && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());
```

В этом условии кроме всего прочего есть проверка на модуль `zend_loader_file_encoded` , которого у меня на моём **виндовом апаче** нет. Нужно было просто внимательнее прочитать. Поставил Линух, установил composer, который через apt install ставится **не**последней версии, и всё работает (да даже если б и последняя - модуль `zend_loader_file_encoded` уже стоит в линуховой версии).

Поправьте, если я не прав! Надеюсь мой опыт будет полезен тем, кто столкнётся с этим!